# Can I buy cryptocurrency being on H1B Visa?

Tags: legal, taxes

Can I Buy/Sell bitcoin/Ethereum or get involved extensively in cryptocurrency? If so how much capital can I invest? I am currently on H1B Visa and wanted to get some insight on this. Thanks!

Comment: Not all people are familiar with Visa specifics. Can you elaborate, why you think this could be relevant? Which country are you from and from which is the Visa?